# Flex: application hangs on "Loading..."

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

I've got a Flex application that loads without issue when offline, but once I embed it in a webpage it hangs on “Loading…”:

[image]

I've tried fiddling with the `-use-network` compile flag to no avail.

I've also watched the network traffic with Charles, and I see two requests for the SWF (ie, `GET /foo.swf`), both of which complete successfully, then nothing else.

What am I missing?

**Edit**: I've determined that it's not a problem with the SWF — when I run a server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, everything loads and runs properly. It only appears to break when I'm using Django's static media server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use [debug version of Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)? If no, install it and hopefully you will see the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using the debug Flash player (according to [Adobe's test site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html)), and unfortunately I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I've determined that the problem "was caused" by Django's gzip middleware. When I turned that off, the swf loaded properly and everything was happy. I have no idea why this might have been, though…

Comment: Hey, im having the same problem, im working with google app engine and my preloader is getting stuck as well. the problem is i cant disable gzip in google app engine (there's a bug in gae), do you know by any chance how can i remove the gzip from the accept-content header in flex client?